# List objects in a combobox in java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a Combobox and i want to fill it with object.

I have tried but i couldn't make it.

Swing java program:

```
String query="select ProductId,Productname from maintable";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet res=pstmt.executeQuery();

    while(res.next())
    {
        String productName = res.getString(1);
        String productId = res.getString(2);
       comboitem comboval = new comboitem(productId, productName);
       combo.addElement(comboval); // ERROR
    }
```

Class comboitem is the class with which Object is created.

```
public class comboitem
{  

private String productId;
   private String productName;

   public comboitem (String productId, String productName) 
   {
      this.productId = productId;
      this.productName = productName;
   }

   public String getProductId() {
      return productId;
   }

   public String getProductName() {
      return productName;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return productName;
   }

}
```

I'm using CComboBox here. Can I list objects in CComboBox?

Comment: *// ERROR*: WHICH error? And what is CComboBox? Where is its javadoc? Also, comboitem should be named ComboItem.

Comment: where's combo definition?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Java, so I'm going to assume you mean [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) and not C++ [`CComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx). That being said, the only error I can see arising from that one method call, again assuming `combo` is a `JComboBox` is that `JComboBox` *has* no `addElement` method. You probably mean to be using a `DefaultComboBoxModel` which *does* have an `addElement` method. So you should do something like

```
MutableComboBoxModel<comboitem> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<comboitem>();
while(res.next())
{
    String productName = res.getString(1);
    String productId = res.getString(2);
    comboitem comboval = new comboitem(productId, productName);
    model.addElement(comboval); // ERROR
}
combo.setModel(model);
```

---

Asides:

- Follow Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters and should use CamelCasing.
- Seem to me [either you have two accounts - which is completely unacceptable, or you and your classmate are working on the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595459/java-combobox-swing). Either way, they answer given by @HovercraftFullOfEels was more than suitable. If you didn't understand, you should ask more question. Or you could simple go to the tutorial, and see [How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)