# How to set item id and display text on DefaultComboBoxModel Java Swing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have table `rk_acgroups`, where list of account type is stored. I want to display name of account types with id, so that I can insert only id rather than text in it't child table.

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel accountGroups() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel groupModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        groupModel.addElement("-- Account Group --");
        MySQLConnection mysql = new MySQLConnection();
        ResultSet groupSet = mysql.query("SELECT * FROM rk_acgroups WHERE status=1 ORDER BY sort_order");
        try {
            while(groupSet.next()) {
                groupModel.addElement(groupSet.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return groupModel;
    }
```

Is there any way to get id of selected item here?
I have found [Java combobox swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595459/java-combobox-swing), but this doesn't helped me! 
(second last comment explained my problem but answer isn't there)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom object to store the "id" and "description". Then you need to create a custom renderer to display the "description" in the combo box. When the item is selected you access the "id" for your other processing.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and example code that you can use.